# DACR read/write on ARM

Tags: android, linux, assembly, arm

I am trying to read and write the DACR on an ARM device running Linux (Android on nexus 5 :)). I have a kernel module. The relevant [instructions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0434b/CIHBCBFE.html) are as follows:

```
MRC p15, 0, <Rd>, c3, c0, 0 ; Read DACR
MCR p15, 0, <Rd>, c3, c0, 0 ; Write DACR
```

I am using C code in the module with assembly inside. I wrote the following to read the current DACR value:

```
unsigned int x = 0;
__asm__("MRC p15, 0, r1, c3, c0, 0;" : "=r" (x));
 printk(KERN_INFO "DACR read - value = %u", x);
```

The above didn't crash the kernel, and the value read out was `3920437248`.

I am not able to write the instruction for DACR write correctly. I was trying to follow from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9568513/682869) and did the following (to write all 1's to DACR to test), but the device crashed and rebooted:

```
__asm__("MVN r1, #0;");
__asm__("MCR p15, 0, r1, c3, c0, 0;");
```

Can anyone advice how to write to DACR correctly ?

Also how to parameterize the above instruction - e.g. for using value of `x` to initialize DACR, would the following be correct:

```
__asm__("MCR p15, 0, %0, c3, c0, 0;" :: "r" (x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you're writing the register correctly alright.

The trouble is, the question is like this:

> I am trying to engage reverse gear on my car driving on the motorway. I was trying to follow the directions in the handbook and moved the gear lever firmly into the "R" position, but my gearbox is now in bits all over the road. Can anyone advise how to engage reverse gear correctly?

You're on a live system. The kernel is already *using* domains. It *needs* access permissions to work correctly. If you declare open season by marking everything as Manager and removing all permission checks, copy-on-write no longer works; every process starts trashing the zero page via their initial mappings instead of triggering the allocation of real backing pages; cats and dogs live together; chaos.

Comment: I suspected the reason, thanks. I just wanted to double check.